# 5 cards bootstrap with gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a container for button and text using card class with black transparent background and border radius for each card like this 
[image]
the problem is the one that i made has a gap between each card like this
[image]
here's the code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26000/)

```css
.kontribusi{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <h3>Ayo Mulai Berkontribusi</h3><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="kontribusi col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
            <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Beri Donasi</a></h4>
            <p class="card-text">Untuk masalah kesehatan perorangan & masyarakat</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kontribusi col-sm-2">
          <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
            <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Galang Dana</a></h4>
            <p class="card-text">Untuk membuat kampanye penggalangan dana</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kontribusi col-sm-2">
          <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
            <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Jadi Relawan</a></h4>
            <p class="card-text">Untuk bantu terlibat dalam aksi kemanusiaan di bidang kesehatan</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kontribusi col-sm-2">
          <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
            <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Butuh Relawan</a></h4>
            <p class="card-text">Untuk dilibatkan dalam aksi kemanusiaan di bidang kesehatan</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="kontribusi col-sm-2">
          <div class="card card-block text-xs-center" >
            <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logistik</a></h4>
            <p class="card-text">Untuk disalurkan kepada pihak yang membutuhkan</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In your second image are no gaps between the cards... do you want a specific margin between the card elements?

Comment: yes but i want it to be responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `.kontribusi` class from the container div and add it to the inner div instead. Then add some padding to the inner div. Here is jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26002/

Comment: how to keep it responsive, because when i streched it to lower size it becomes messy?

Comment: add `margin-bottom:10px ` to the class. You can use media query if you don't want that margin above tablet resolution. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26006/

Comment: wow it works, but how to make all the cards have the same height?

Comment: @Wallflower To make them all same height and keep them responsive I removed bootstrap columns and had to basically rewrite the whole thing using flexbox. Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26010/

Comment: @Wallflower did this help?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your initial code use this instead:

```css
.kontribusi{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
  }
```

Comment: I've checked this solution and this breaks the grid - the whole grid will be shifted to the left. Have a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26003/

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead, i am sure this will help you.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.wrapper{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h3>Ayo Mulai Berkontribusi</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
          <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logistik</a></h4>
          <p class="card-text">Untuk disalurkan kepada pihak yang membutuhkan</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
          <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logistik</a></h4>
          <p class="card-text">Untuk disalurkan kepada pihak yang membutuhkan</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
          <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logistik</a></h4>
          <p class="card-text">Untuk disalurkan kepada pihak yang membutuhkan</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
          <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logistik</a></h4>
          <p class="card-text">Untuk disalurkan kepada pihak yang membutuhkan</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
          <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logistik</a></h4>
          <p class="card-text">Untuk disalurkan kepada pihak yang membutuhkan</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is, bootstrap class has predefined behavior and it is not always ok to add more styles to it inside, it is better to let them be a holder and then you have a wrapper around the main content and then add your custom styles to it. Please tell me what you think about the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Check the below Fiddle I hope You are looking for this I didn't add the basic styles  but make the basic layout you are looking for you can customize as your own style .

I just added an extra column  to make the grids .

```
.col-centered {
 float: none;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 }
```

[Updated BootstrapGrid Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26007/)

hope It Helps.

Comment: the gap is too narrow and the button is sticking to the border

Comment: I told before i didn't add much css and still didn't a lot just  fixed spacing issue . See the Updated Fiddle